# Differentiability of $0 \leq f(x,y) \leq |x|^\alpha \cdot |x|^\beta$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $0 \leq f(x,y) \leq |x|^\alpha \cdot |x|^\beta$

$\forall{(x,y) \in B_{\delta_0}(0,0)}$ for some $\delta_0 > 0$.

I have to prove that if $\alpha+\beta \leq 1$, there always exists $f$ that is **not** differentiable in $(0,0)$.

Thank you.

Comment: $f(x,y) = x^2 y^2$ is differentiable everywhere and satisfies the conditions. Are you sure you got the direction of the relation correct?

Comment: No, you're right, I got the inequation wrong: it is alpha+beta <= 1. Now it wouldn't be so hard to prove it is not differentiable for alpha+beta < 1, but I don't know what to do with the case alpha+beta = 1.

After that I need to show that there is always a function that meets the first condition, but that it is not differentiable.

Comment: Well, $f(x,y) = 0$ satisfies $f(x,y) \le |x|^0|y|^1$.

Comment: It's not saying every function that satisfies it isn't differentiable at the origin, it's saying that there exists a function that depends on $\alpha$ and $\beta$ that is not differentiable at the origin.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x,y)= |x|^\alpha |y|^\beta$$ does it, the directional derivative in direction $(1,1)$ doesn't exist as for $h \in \mathbb R$, $$f(h,h)/h = |h|^{\alpha + \beta}/h =\mathrm{sgn}(h)\cdot h^{\alpha + \beta -1},$$ which has no limit as $h \rightarrow 0$ because $\alpha + \beta - 1\leq 0$.

Comment: That was much easier than I thought, I was overthinking it. Thanks a lot!